# JTable cell editor to accept numbers only

Tags: java, swing, jtable, bigdecimal, tablecelleditor

I want to add a cell editor in a JTable that accepts numbers only (BigDecimal type to be precise). I have experimented all the proposed code and have read also all the similar questions here. However none of the proposed solutions worked for me. The documentation available in the internet including Oracle's website is not so good on the topic I'm looking for.

Please, notice: The cell editor must accept numbers only, actually numbers and decimal separators (. or ,).

Answer (score 4):

Use e.g. `JSpinner` (with `SpinnerNumberModel`) or `JFormattedTextField` (with necessary formatter) as the editor.

Answer (score 4):

Along with StanislavL excellent suggests, you can try using a [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html).

Check out [MDP's Weblog](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for some excellent examples

Comment: @StanislavL If we could get a `JFormattedTextField` with a `DocumentHandler` I think we'd be onto a final solution ;)